# How do I keep my python loop going if there is an error with an SDE workspace?

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase, loop, workspace, compression

I have a folder with several .SDE connections.  I want my Python code to execute various SDE maintenance procedures (such as compress) on each of these databases.  If there is a bad/corrupt/not permissioned .SDE file in the workspace, the process doesn't execute on any of the other databases either. How do I get it to attempt to compress each database in the workspace, even if one fails?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/Scripts/DatabaseConnections"

workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "SDE")

try:
    for workspace in workspaces:
        arcpy.Compress_management(workspace)
except:  
    arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, just reorganize your try/except block and put it inside the for loop:

```
for workspace in workspaces:
    try:
        arcpy.Compress_management(workspace)
    except:  
        arcpy.GetMessages()
```